# In the python for unity package is there any way to import external libraries like numpy and mediapipe?

Tags: python, c#, unity-game-engine

```
public class HandTrackingPoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        string scriptPath = Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "PyPackage/HandNode.py");
        PythonRunner.RunFile(scriptPath);
    }
    
}
```

I've got this so far but I don't know how to give it a folder that has all the libraries that I want to use

I tried using ironpython which kept crashing my unity so this seems like the only method that works

Comment: Not familiar with this package, but it probably has something more to do with using an interpreter that has those libraries installed. I'm not sure how to designate which interpreter is being used by unity, but that would be a good place to start

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.